# Как извлечь определённые значения из файла json?

Tags: python, json

Мне нужно получить определенные значения из файла json (study instance uid, x,y,z, diameter(mm), study id)

```
{
{
"doctors": [
    {
        "comment": "Нет",
        "id": "000"
    },
    {
        "comment": "Нет очагов",
        "id": "005"
    },
    {
        "comment": "очагов нет, плевропульмональные спайки",
        "id": "013"
    },
    {
        "comment": "очагов нет",
        "id": "002"
    },
    {
        "comment": "Нет",
        "id": "004"
    },
    {
        "comment": "Нет очагов",
        "id": "005+"
    }
],
"ids": {
    "accession number": "RLAD31D006-1864",
    "study id": "RLS5A09001KDC6-N0002",
    "study instance uid": "1.2.276.0.7230010.3.1.2.1417964692.346944"
},
"nodules": [
    [
        {
            "000": null,
            "002": null,
            "005+": null,
            "013": {
                "diameter (mm)": 6.00000000000007,
                "expert decision": [
                    {
                        "comment": "",
                        "decision": "confirmed_partially",
                        "id": "СВЕ",
                        "machine learning": false,
                        "proper size": true,
                        "type": "м"
                    }
                ],
                "series no": "4 5",
                "type": "м",
                "version": "4.0",
                "x": 73.0,
                "y": 296.0,
                "z": 1728.7,
                "z type": "mm"
            }
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "000": {
                "diameter (mm)": 4.0,
                "expert decision": [
                    {
                        "comment": "неверный размер",
                        "decision": "confirmed_partially",
                        "id": "СВЕ",
                        "machine learning": false,
                        "proper size": false,
                        "type": "с"
                    }
                ],
                "series no": "4 5",
                "type": "с",
                "version": "4.0",
                "x": 123.0,
                "y": 167.0,
                "z": 1689.5,
                "z type": "mm"
            },
            "002": null,
            "004": null,
            "005": null,
            "005+": null,
            "013": null
        }
    ]
]
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете воспользоваться встроенным модулем [json](https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-json.html)

Например, если данные лежат в файле `data.json`

```py
import json
 
with open('data.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
study_uid = data['ids']['study instance uid']
stydu_id = data['ids']['study id']

res = []
for l in data['nodules']: # возможно, тут имелось ввиду 'modules' ?
    for el in l:
        for v in el.values():  # возвращает итератор по значениям словаря
            if v is not None: #  null в json "равен" None в Python
                res.append({'x': v['x'], 'y': v['y'], 'z': v['z'], 'diameter (mm)': v['diameter (mm)']})
```

Последнюю строчку можно записать разными способами

Например, "универсальный" метод : `dict(map(lambda x: (x, v[x]), ["x", "y", "z", "diameter (mm)"]))`

Также можете сделать проверку на существование ключа в словаре `"x" in v` или, наоборот, отсутствие `"x" not in v`

Подробнее про словари: https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/slovari-dict-funkcii-i-metody-slovarej.html

Официальная документация:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: я бы еще добавил проверку наличия параметра, перед его чтением.

Comment: Выдает ошибку : AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'